# Fixed time frame in Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have plotted temperature sensor data using chart js. What I need is to fix the X-axis frame to 30 seconds and let the incoming temperature data to pass through the fixed frame, and just updating the x-axis values.
My current code fixes the time frame but after 30 seconds the data are overwritten on the previous data and it repeats after every 30 seconds. You can see the code below.

```
<script>
  var chart = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Room',
        borderColor: '#17A2B8',
        data: [],
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: '#B3D9E0'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            min: TimeMin,
            max: TimeMax
          },
          display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Time'
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Temperature'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };

  window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, chart);
  };

  //Get the current second
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var TimeMin = s;
  var TimeMax = s + 30;

  function addData(tempData){
    d = new Date();
    if (chart.data.datasets.length > 0) {
      chart.data.labels.push(d.getHours() + d.getMinutes() + d.getSeconds());
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data.push(tempData);
      });
      window.myLine.update();
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have defined `TimeMin` and `TimeMax` variables and have set them to the current time in seconds and current time plus thirty seconds, respectively and I have put them in the `xAxes` options; `min: TimeMin` and `max: TimeMax`.
Can anybody help me to let the data pass through the fixed time frame and not overwritten to the previous ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the answer. setTimeout() function should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to set `TimeMin` and `TimeMax`.
There should be a function to be called for example every 30 seconds and remove the first element of labels and data that are shown on the chart. See the updated `addData()` function, below.

```
function addData(sensorData){
    d = new Date();
    if (chart.data.datasets.length > 0) {
      chart.data.labels.push('(' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() + ') ' + d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate());
      //The setTimeout function is called every 30 seconds and runs the "Action" function.
      setTimeout(Action, 30000);
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data.push(sensorData);
      });
      //The Action function removes the first element of displayed labels and pushed data.
      function Action() {
        chart.data.labels.shift();
        chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
          dataset.data.shift();
        });
      }
    window.myLine.update();
    }
  };
```

Comment: But there is an animation issue on the `shift()` function. Shifting is not smooth all the time and there is a lag between shift and chart update.